# How to determine PostgreSQL column data type based on numpy data types?

Tags: python, postgresql, numpy, psycopg2

On the Python side I have a list of signals, each signal is a `numpy.ndarray`.

Among the signals the dtype varies - including `numpy.uint8`, `numpy.uint16`, `numpy.uint32`, `numpy.float64`, and `numpy.bytes_`.

Eventually I'd like to pass the signals to a table in PostgreSQL, each signal being a column. I'm now stuck at the ADD COLUMN step as it's required to specify the data type for each column in PostgreSQL.

As I use psycopg2 as the adapter, I found [this table](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) in the documentation but haven't found any information to help adding columns with proper data types in a dynamic way.

My idea / approach would be - considering there're just 5 known dtype among the signals I have, I could:

1. iterate through the list of signals
2. get the first element of each signal, find its dtype
3. determine the appropriate PostgreSQL data type for each signal
4. generate a corresponding list of PostgreSQL data types
5. use the generated list to pass data types when adding columns

I'm not sure if this is the optimal way though. Is there an existing lib that does the job? Or is there a better way of coding this approach?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant at all but in the end I used this method:

Read the `type()` of the first element in each signal and convert it into a `str`, which is later passed to a function to basically match the corresponding PostgreSQL data type. *Note that only `numpy` data types that are relevant my project are covered.*

```
def db_data_type(data_type):
    # Input is string of data type
    conversion_table = {
        "<class 'numpy.uint8'>":    'int2',     # 0 to 255          # -32768 to 32767
        "<class 'numpy.uint16'>":   'int4',     # 0 to 65535        # -2147483648 to 2147483647
        "<class 'numpy.uint32'>":   'int8',     # 0 to 4924967295   # -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
        "<class 'numpy.int8'>":     'int2',     # -128 to 127
        "<class 'numpy.int16'>":    'int2',     # -32768 to 32767
        "<class 'numpy.int32'>":    'int4',     # -2147483648 to 2147483647
        "<class 'numpy.float64'>":  'float8',   # double
        "<class 'numpy.bytes_'>":   'text',
    }
    return conversion_table[data_type]
```

Basically when I iterate through a bunch of signals (columns in database table) I'll get a list of signal names (column names in DB) and a list of data types (column data types in DB). And here's the code for `psycopg2` to generate the SQL query:

```
def db_create_columns(conn, table, columns, types):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for i in range(len(columns)):
        sql_add_column = psycopg2.sql.SQL("""ALTER TABLE {} ADD COLUMN {} {} ;""") \
            .format(psycopg2.sql.Identifier(table),
                    psycopg2.sql.Identifier(columns[i]),
                    psycopg2.sql.Identifier(types[i]))
        try:
            cur.execute(sql_add_column)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error occurred when adding data column [%s].\n%s' % (columns[i], e))
    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    return
```

Here the function arguments are: connection to DB, table name, list of column names, list of data types.

If there's a better way to do this please don't hesitate to point out. I'd appreciate it a lot.